# NodeJS - can I "free" a required module?

Tags: node.js, module, requirejs, load, free

As I may know, a required module is cached and be there all the time no matter how many times `require(...)` is called.

```
function f1() {
    const m = require("/path/to/my/module")
    ...
}
```

In my situation, my `module` keeps having code updated, so I want to load and free every time I use in `f1()`.

How can I do that? If I don't use `require`, what should I use?

Thanks

Comment: https://nodejs.org/api/modules.html#modules_require_cache You can delete them from the require cache

Comment: You can delete your module from the module cache and then `require()` it again.  This won't necessarily "free" anything.  But, it will allow your new version of the module to load.  I am really hoping this is not something you're trying to do in production (rewriting code constantly and then reloading it) because there's probably a lot better way to solve whatever problem it is you're trying to solve.

Comment: Keep in mind code does not have to live in modules. You can `eval()` code whenever you want too. It doesn't have to be in a module.  A module is a convenient disk-based package that follows a particular convention, but isn't the only way to run code. Again, we could probably help you a lot better if you described the actual problem you're trying to solve. Right now, this is a bit of an [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem) where you described an issue you ran into with your solution without describing the actual main problem you're trying to solve.

Comment: I don't think its good idea to disturbed your module just because of code updates, can you post your problem why you want to do that

Comment: My nodejs server is interfacing with a module, which is not yet completed. The client wants my server not to reset everytime they update their module. But I found `modules_require_cache` helpful as some above answer suggests. If you have solutions that you think better, feel free to share. Thanks